Multiple netcat connections in old version of linux
I'm running a 32-bits old version of CentOS in a offline LAN network. I'd like to setup communication between all hosts, pretty much like nc -l 5555 + nc <ip1> 5555 works. Well, I'm aware that netcat only allows a single running instance for each port, however I'd like an alternative I could build from source (or even a script using the current netcat) that supports multiple connections at once, such that I could setup like a hub for all clients inside the network. I'd like to get like a group chat running, where a client sends a message to the hub that broadcasted to all clients (except the one who sent it). Is it possible?
Linux 2.6.18-92.el5 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Possibly this approach. Each party should run one sender and one receiver. A sender may be preceded by while IFS= read -r message; do printf 'nickname: %s\n' "$message" |. A receiver may be piped to ts (timestamp). An approach where one socat (per party) is both a sender and a receiver is possible (e.g. UDP-DATAGRAM with both ports equal), but you will still want to use different ttys for input and output, to prevent incoming messages from interfering with what you type.

If you need to handle multiple simultaneous connections on your "hub", take a look at netcat as a multithread server. You'll have to use something like tcpserver that can handle multiple operations
For consecutive connections (one at a time), it may be simpler to use a shell script that just forwards the output to your other clients and restarts netcat after it finishes.

If you mean a literal group chat message service, then you might prefer an IRC server, like inspIRCd
